# ASP.NET MVC 3: manage users and roles inside the internet application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, asp.net-roles

When I now want to manage (create/delete/edit) Users and Roles for my MVC 3 internet application, I need to go to inetmgr on the server and change the .NET Roles / .NET Users there.

Is it possible to manage these users and roles from within the MVC 3 internet application itself (without having to go to the inetmgr on the server itself)?

Which changes should be done (to do AccountController I guess)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats wrong with:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(User.Username, "Create");
```

and:

```
Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(User.Username, "Create");
```

Or if you are talking about managing roles themselves:

```
Roles.CreateRole("View");
```

Using these methods you could then create action methods and views to allow role management from within your application.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know that you could actually do that directly via the site. Cool!
I guess working with Users is just calling Membership (System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers()).

Comment: Exactly. Although! What I do is have my own user table. With this I can store user IDs against other tables such as bookings or orders (or whatever) and include information such as address/postcode etc. Then if I'm working with roles I simply get the Membership user based on my DB record. Hope it helps :)